# Ajax success response not displaying echo message from PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to develop an 'Add to cart' functionality in my PHP project. Here is the code.

This is the form from where I take the product data.

**form**

```
<form class="product-form" method="POST">
                        <input name="product_id" type="hidden"
                            value="<?=$data['id']?>">
                        <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="1">
                        <button name="trending-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add To
                            Cart</button>
                    </form>
```

**ajax**

```
$(".product-form").submit(function () {
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var button_content = $(this).find("button[type=submit]");
    button_content.html("Adding...");
    $.ajax({
      url: "./includes/add-to-cart.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
        $(".cart-quantity").html(response);
        button_content.html("Add to Cart");
      },
    });
    return false;
  });
```

The "alert(response)" doesn't display anything at all.

The PHP code which calls cart object functions.

**PHP**

```
    <?php
ob_start();


require("classes/Database.php");
$db = new Database();

require("classes/Cart.php");
$cart = new Cart($db);


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['product_id'] != null && $_POST['user_id'] != null) {
        $cart->addToCart($_POST['product_id'], $_POST['user_id']);
    }

    $total = $cart->showCartQuantity();
    echo $total;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Side note: cheking your `$_POST` indices against `null` is not sufficient (it can still produce "Undefined index" notices). Use `isset()` instead.

Comment: As you're making a webshop i doubt you'd want empty product ids/ids to be added to your cart aswell; use `empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use **relative** paths with `$.ajax()`. You should instead use the URL (including FQDN) where you want to POST data.

> Check your network tab in your browser and find the XHR request for more information.

Also, you should add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour of the HTML `<form>`, which is to refresh the page (ie. change the browser location to the URL specified in the HTML `<form>`'s `action` attribute).

```js
$(".product-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var button_content = $(this).find("button[type=submit]");
    button_content.html("Adding...");

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/ajaxfile.php", // Full URL of PHP file
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
        $(".cart-quantity").html(response);
        button_content.html("Add to Cart");
        },
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you ^^